# Adiabatic Surfaces in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

In some lecture notes on thermodynamics there is a discussion as to whether by assuming the first law of thermodynamics alone we can prove the existence of a adiabatic surface in three dimensions. To prove that it is not possible the following theory is used[image: Formula about what type of motions generate a surface in 3D]

Can anyone prove this or provide a link to a proof?

Comment: This is a special case of the so-called theorem of Frobenius for differential forms (equations), see e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology). A geometric/intuitive proof is in Aminov: The Geometry of Vector Fields, and you can get a free peek here http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Vector-Fields-Routledge-Revivals/dp/0415706866/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1440873863&sr=1-1&keywords=aminov&pebp=1440873874152&perid=04R36018JBKSSD6SBZNJ (the first few pages is about this issue)